# Android - Consume onTouch of parent view having multiple Clickable children

Tags: android, touch, gesture, ontouchlistener

I have a `ListView` in an `Activity`. The `ListView` rows are `LinearLayout`s each and contain two children `View`s, both are `clickable`. The structure is like this -

```
 ______________________________
|      |                       |
|______|_______________________|
```

Now, I want to keep the two items `clickable` and detect a swipe action on the parent `View`, i.e. `the LinearLayout`.

Could you please suggest me what would be the best approach for this?

Comment: Look at the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. Does this mean I have to extend `LinearLayout` and use that as the container of the the `ListView` rows?

Comment: Yes, as you need to override that method + the `onTouch` method.

Comment: Hi. Is there a way to get the position of ListView item / corresponding object of ListAdapter in those methods?

Comment: I guess you could pass the row position to your custom `LinearLayout` in the `getView` method of the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try your solution. Meanwhile kindly let me know if there's an example.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. If you could post this as answer, I would accept it as the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I want to keep the two items clickable and detect a swipe action
>   on the parent View, i.e. the LinearLayout.

You could create your own row `View` which extends `LinearLayout` and will wrap those two child views. For this override the [`onInterceptTouchEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and the [`onTouch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) methods to detect the swipe. If you need to know which row are you currently swiping you could have your custom view remember its position in the list and update the position in the `getView` method of the adapter.

Another option, I think, would be to have an overlay view on top of the normal row view which will handle the swipe.

Answer (score 1):

In your `BaseAdapter` override `getView`, and get a reference to each child and set `onClickLister` for each of them, every time the `getView` called, sample:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent,false);
        }

        final MyClass item = (MyClass)getItem(position);

        View child1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.child1);
        child1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("tag", "child1 from item "+ position +" , is clicked.");

            }
        });

        View child2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.child2);
        child2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("tag", "child2 from item "+ position +" , is clicked.");

            }
        });

        return convertView;}
```

and for Swipe, extend your `LinearLayout` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent` in it, and pass this to `GestureDetector` and handle scroll on it.
for more info about `GestureDetector` and Swipe, look into Google for `GestureDetector` and `SimpleOnGestureListener` samples.